# Socket, bound to an address, cannot connect to a listener except when bound to 127.0.0.1 on Win XP

Tags: java, sockets, windows-xp

I created a socket and bound it to 127.0.0.254 and then tried to connect to an httpListener on 0.0.0.0 443, using

```
socket= new Socket();
socket.bind("127.0.0.254:0");
socket.connect("127.0.0.1",443);
```

This fails on the connect with an exception "No route to host "
The same block of code works fine on win 8 though.

ADDITINAL INFO:

I'm binding it to 0. My problem is that, I'm probing the listener every 5 minutes to see if it is up. For this, I tried binding a socket to the .254 address and then determine if it is a probe or real by the address of the socket trying to connect. This is not working on XP as the socket connection fails. But if I dont bind, the socket will take a 127.0.0.1 address and I cannot differentiate. Any workaround to my scenario?

Comment: Does the call `socket.bind("127.0.0.254:0");` succeed? Do you test its result for failure? Does the machine your calling `bind()`on has an interface setup carrying `127.0.0.254`?

Comment: The bind succeeds with no error, I checked. It only fails when you connect it to the 127.0.0.1 443 address. 
The listener being on 0.0.0.0 443 means that it picks up any ip on the same port. At least that's what I assume it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect XP doesn't treat loopback adapters properly with regards to the 127.x.y.z address range.  I suspect if you connect to 127.0.0.1 from another socket binded to 127.0.0.1, you'll be ok.  But you are using the same source and destination port (443) in your example.

Do you really need the client port to be on 443 as well? It typically makes sense for servers (the listening socket) to bind to the well known port, but clients can bind to any port.

Hence, this should work for all platforms:

```
socket= new Socket();
socket.bind("127.0.0.1:0");
socket.connect("127.0.0.1",443);
```

Or better yet, don't bind explicitly. The OS will detect you are making a connection to loopback and do the appropriate binding implicitly.

```
socket= new Socket();
socket.connect("127.0.0.1",443);
```